# How can I obtain data from a server (HTTP POST) during class construction without putting the HTTP POST in the constructor itself?

Tags: c#, constructor, httprequest

I have a class that in order to have all its properties fully populated it needs to obtain some data from the server.

Currently I have a call to the server in its constructor like so:

```
public class GeometryObject
{
    public GeometryObject(string partName, CADFileType partType)
    {
        InitializeTransformParameters(); 
        CreateDefaultInternalParameters(); 
        CADFile = Server.GetCADFileAsync(partName, partType).Result; // not great having a time consuming action in the constructor but not sure how else to do this.                             
    } 
}
```

`Server.GetCADFileAsync()` is essentially a wrapper for `HttpClient.PostAsync()`.

Although this works (provided the call succeeds!!), it smells a bit like a bad design.  How is this kind of thing usually approached?  I'm using C# 6.

Comment: Rather than a public constructor, normally a static factory which can make the calls and *only when it's ready* constructs the actual object is a fairly common pattern.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - thanks I'll look into that.  Any suggested links to read?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen it done, but it's not exactly good. A more common approach uses a **Factory Method**, like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    // private constructor
    private MyClass() {}

    // public static method to wrap the constructor. 
    // "Create" is also a common name here,
    // but I prefer "Load" when I *know* it's gonna take a while
    public static MyClass Load()
    {
        // We can call the constructor here, because it's a member of the class
        var result = new MyClass();
        
        // populate required fields here

        
        return result;       
    }
}
```

Then, instead of `new MyClass()` you'd use the type like this:

```
var myVariable = MyClass.Load();
```

And so we would adapt the code in the question like this:

```
public class GeometryObject
{
    private GeometryObject() 
    {
        // normal/fast initialization can still go here (but doesn't have to)
        InitializeTransformParameters(); 
        CreateDefaultInternalParameters(); 
    }

    public static GeometryObject Load(string partName, CADFileType partType)
    {
        var result = new GeometryObject();
        result.CADFile = Server.GetCADFileAsync(partName, partType).Result;
        return result;                            
    }         
}
```

Comment: thanks that makes perfect sense and I can then adjust it to make it async await as needed 